# ORA-00936: missing expression CREATE TABLE when creating procedure and add sequence number in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

when I run below code in oracle developer, I get error

```
5/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/9       PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
Errors: check compiler log
```

My code :

```
CREATE TABLE table_prc4 (
    name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE pp_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmembe (
    str IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_prc4 VALUES (
        SELECT
            regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts 
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL 
    )
Commit ; 
END ;

BEGIN
    addnewmembe(pp_seq ,'faezeh,mina,pari');
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your good response, but my main problem is to create a sequence for the ID in the column table table_prc4 , and in the procedure, I don't know how the ID column should get the sequence value for each name in each row.

Answer (score 2):

A few errors:

- insert can't have both `VALUES` and `SELECT` statement. In your case, remove `VALUES`
- you have to terminate every statement with a semi-colon
- PL/SQL procedures should be terminated by a slash character (if you're running everything as a script)
- if procedure accepts only one parameter, then don't pass two parameters when calling the procedure

When fixed:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_prc4 ( name VARCHAR2(20) );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE pp_seq MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmembe ( str IN VARCHAR2 ) AS
  2  BEGIN
  3    INSERT INTO table_prc4
  4      SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts
  5      FROM dual
  6      CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
  7    Commit ;
  8  END ;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2    addnewmembe('faezeh,mina,pari');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_prc4;

NAME
--------------------
faezeh
mina
pari

SQL>
```